ActiveMQ Artemis: consumer stops processing messages under high volume of messages
We are seeing an issue when ActiveMQ Artemis would just stop processing messages with no exception output when high load of messages are sent to a queue.
Thread is going into TIMED_WAITING, and on enabling the ActiveMQ Artemis debug logging following logs are generated:
[DEBUG] 2024-08-16 08:04:21  org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl -> ServerConsumerImpl [id=0, filter=null, binding=LocalQueueBinding [address=dataLoaderEventLoadQueue, queue=QueueImpl[name=dataLoaderEventLoadQueue, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=localhost], temp=false]@cdc51ba, filter=null, name=dataLoaderEventLoadQueue, clusterName=dataLoaderEventLoadQueueb22e4460-5561-11ef-82f9-0242ac10002d], closed=false] is busy for the lack of credits. Current credits = 0 Can't receive reference Reference[6466728861]:RELIABLE:CoreMessage[messageID=6466728861, durable=true, userID=534d776f-5ba2-11ef-8405-0242ac10002d, priority=4, timestamp=Fri Aug 16 07:37:01 UTC 2024, expiration=Fri Aug 23 07:37:01 UTC 2024, durable=true, address=dataLoaderEventLoadQueue, size=608, properties=TypedProperties[__AMQ_CID=c2b7ea3e-5a24-11ef-8405-0242ac10002d, _AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1, _AMQ_LVQ_NAME=102-255793408260991718]]@515090880
[DEBUG] 2024-08-16 08:04:21  org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl -> QueueImpl[name=dataLoaderEventLoadQueue, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=localhost],
 temp=false]@cdc51ba::All the consumers were busy, giving up now

We have set ConsumerWindowSize value 0 as we do not buffer messages at client side. If this is not set, then even after pausing the queue messages were being consumed.
We use ActiveMQ Artemis 2.32.0.
[EDIT]
Adding thread dump from the consumer
"DataLoad-EventLoadMessageProcessorThread" #204 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=22071.75ms elapsed=51544.03s tid=0x00007fb3cbf164f0 nid=0x1ea in Object.wait()  [0x00007fb15e3eb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.10/Native Method)
    - waiting on <no object reference available>
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:265)
    - locked <0x000000041600e5a0> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:372)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:209)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:129)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:66)
    at com.blueplanet.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.processMessagesInBatch(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:113)
    at com.blueplanet.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.run(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.10/Thread.java:840)

Consumer count is 1
Delivering count is 0
Message count is 67819

The DEBUG messages you're seeing in the ActiveMQ Artemis log are normal for situations where the consumers are busy and can't receive any more messages (which would be quite common when using consumerWindowSize=0). That is why the logs are at DEBUG and not WARN or ERROR. In such a situation the broker can't dispatch the message(s) to the consumer(s) until they become free. For additional debugging info please see this answer. Also, it's worth upgrading.

@JustinBertram the consumer here we mean the artemis consumer right? what we are observing is that the consumer is stuck for indefinite time and thread is in wating state. Basically Consumer stops processing messages after certain period of time and does not come back to its original state of processing messages and we can still see there are messages in the queue awaiting processing.

Can you provide a thread dump from the consumer? Also, what's the message count, consumer count, and delivering count on the queue?

@JustinBertram Consumer count is 1, Delivering count is 0 and Message count is 67819. I have also updated the original description with the thread dump and other details you asked

Hi @JustinBertram any update on this?
TIA

At this point I recommend you upgrade to the latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis. If you still encounter this problem then work up a reproducible test-case and open a Jira. At this point all the evidence suggests this is some kind of bug, but you need to rule out the possibility that the problem has already been fixed either explicitly or implicitly.

@JustinBertram We were using JMSConsumer.receive() method, Consumer was waiting indefinitely to receive the  message. What we observed that if there is continuous flow of the messages to Artemis (We observed continuous flow of the messages for 6-7 hrs), then Artemis broker was not passing the message to the consumer and hence processing stops even the messages were in the queue and no inflow of the message. Upgrading the  Artemis to latest (2.37.0),  didn't help.
But when we replaced the JMSConsumer.receive() with JMSConsumer.receive(timeout)  we didn't encounter the issue.

Since you're still hitting this problem in the latest release I recommend you open a Jira with a clear explanation of the issue and steps to reproduce.
